# how a signal to a process affects its child threads?

Tags: c, linux, function, sleep, interrupt

gurus, I got 2 problems with the linux functions:

1. sleep

   As far as I know sleep in process will get interrupted by any signals sent its process. Is this right?
2. still the sleep

   If I create several threads in the process, and I insert sleep functions in the threads, and, then if I send signals into the process, will the sleep be interrupted?

BTW if I send a signal to a process, when the process get the signal, will it send to its child threads?

Thanx for your answers

Answer (score 3):

> 1: sleep,
>      as i know sleep in process will get interrupted by any signals sent its process.
>      is it right?

It will get interrupted, unless the particular signal is ignored or blocked using [`sigprocmask`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigprocmask.html).

> 2: still the sleep,
>      if I create several threads in the process, and i insert sleep functions
>      in the threads, and then if i send signals into the process, will the sleep
>      be interrupted?

Only one thread receives a signal sent to the process even if there are several threads within that process that have that signal unblocked. See [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) for more details. The standard way to handle signals in a multi-threaded process is to have all signals blocked in all threads but the one that handles the signals (normally it's the main thread).

> BTW: If i send a signal to a process , when the process get the signal, 
>      will it send to its child threads?

It won't.

However, if the process is a session group leader controlling the terminal, its group will receive `SIGHUP` signal when the session leader terminates. Also, when a process group becomes orphaned its processes get sent `SIGHUP` followed  by a `SIGCONT`.

Comment: :Maxim, thanx your answer, it's very helpful. Can you give me some references of these mechanism.

Comment: The Signal Concept link I mentioned is pretty good. You may also like to read the chapter about signals in Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment by W. Richard Stevens.

Answer (score 1):

1: Yes that's right.  If you examine `errno` after the `sleep()` it will be set to `EINTR` (interrupted).

2: Each thread can set it's own signal mask using `pthread_sigmask()` and if it blocks the signal it won't be sent it.  However it's undefined which of the threads receives the signal, if they don't block the signal explicitly.

You can send a signal directly to a specific thread using `pthread_kill()`, however.

Answer (score 0):

A process-directed signal is delivered to *one* of the process's threads.  If that thread is sleeping, it will be woken.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should use condition wait instead of sleep.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview

You only need to read section "Condition Variables". It helps you get overview of pthread for your purpose.